# Why when exists overflow .class{position:fixed;} fail?

Tags: css

This error is visible ONLY when you open from phone:

```css
    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
    background-color:brown;
    color:#000;
    }
    .container{
    background-color:gold;
    min-height:100%;
    }
    #logo{
    background-color:indigo;
    color:papayawhip;
    border:1px dashed #000;
    font-weight:bold;
    position:fixed;
    padding:1em;
    right:0;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Pure CSS Menu</title>

    </head><body>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>why_any_overflow_break_the_css_position_fixed_on_the_elements_if_this_is_open_using_phone?</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
        <p>without overflow this work greath!</p>
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

In our search, also we save the page from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
this works great on the phone! But by only adding the line:

```
<p>why_any_overflow_break_the_css_position_fixed_on_the_elements_if_this_is_open_using_phone?</p>
```

then the MENU TOP is broken. Why ?

For open/load FROM PHONE the Mozilla Developer Network page **with overflow**:
https://deliciasnaturales.com/phone/position_MDN_overflow_1.htm

For open/see FROM PHONE the Mozilla Developer Network page **without** overflow:
https://deliciasnaturales.com/phone/position_MDN_overflow_0.htm

For load from PHONE this code page **with overflow**:
https://deliciasnaturales.com/phone/code_overflow_1.html

For load from PHONE this code page **without overflow**:
https://deliciasnaturales.com/phone/code_overflow_0.html

note:
the "overflow" is only this line:

```
<p>why_any_overflow_break_the_css_position_fixed_on_the_elements_if_this_is_open_using_phone?</p>
```

There are two questions:

1. Why does this error exist only from phones?
2. What is the solution?

Thanks

We try to obtain a responsive template, and even if exists overflow, elements continue in position fixed.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "from phone" - what model of phone and browser are you using?

Comment: ...why are you linking to `https://deliciasnaturales.com/` and why does it hold a copy of MDN's content?

Comment: from ANY phone the code break, (element LOGO lost "position:fixed")

Comment: @Dai you can see our messgae: **...In our search, also we save the page from Mozilla Developer Network...** (why we save this page?) for do test!, (they are the maximum professionañs!) then we confirm: if exists OVERFLOW elements lost "fixed position" if is open from cell phone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks @Community, simply the element "**#logo**" (**only when is loaded from phone**) lost the property `position:fixed;` when exists a TABLE with overflow. Therefore: 1 why? 2 exists solution?